# $f_U(t)=f_{X,Z}(t,1)+f_{Y,Z}(t,0)$ if $U=X $ if $Z=1$ and $U=Y$ if $Z=0$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, density-function

Suppose $Z$ is a bernouli variable with parameter $p$. $Z,X,Y$ are independent random variables. Now $U$ be a random variable such that

$$U(\omega)=\begin{cases}X(\omega) & \text{when }Z(\omega)=1\\ Y(\omega) & \text{when }Z(\omega)=0\end{cases}$$

From this can we say that

$f_U(t)=f_{X,Z}(t,1)+f_{Y,Z}(t,0)$

Comment: $$f_U(t)=\begin{cases}f_{X}(t)& \text{when }Z=1\\ f_Y(t) & \text{when }Z=0\end{cases}$$
 does not even make sense.

Comment: To compute $f_U$ you need independence of $Z$ an $(X,Y)$.

Comment: I have thay $Z,X,Y$ are independent. Sorry i missed that part.

Comment: If, $X$ is continuous with a density and $z$ is discrete then $(X,Z)$ has no density function. I don't consider $f_{X,Z}$ as  a valid notation (but there may be some books that use such bad notations).

Comment: Well grimmet uses these notations

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $X$ and $Y$ have densities $f_X$ and $f_Y$ we can compute $f_U$ as follows:

$$P(U \leq t)=P(X\leq t, Z=1) +P(Y\leq t, Z=0)$$ $$=pP(X\leq t)+(1-p)P(Y\leq t).$$ Differentiating this we get $f_U(t)=pf_X(t)+(1-p)f_Y(t)$ almost everywhere (w.r.t. Lebesgue measure).

Comment: We can not differentitate since it is not given that the density functions are continuous

Comment: If a r.v. has  a density then the density is the derivative of the CDF (almost everywhere w.r.t Lebesgue measure). Equality of densitites is understood in a.e. sense, There is no need for continuity of densities.  @SohamChatterjee

Comment: Can you show without using measure. Since i dont know measure theory. I haven't done the courae on it

Comment: If you want to avoid measure theory you have to assume continuity of densities. Even the definition of density function involves Lebesgue measure. @SohamChatterjee